# The superior limit of a sequence of functions?

Tags: limits, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Problem statement:

> Let $\{E_n\}$ be a sequence of sets and let $E^* = \limsup_n{E_n}$. Prove that
>
> $$
> \chi_{E^*}(x) = \limsup_{n\to\infty}{\chi_{E_n}(x)}
> $$
> where $\chi_X$ is the characteristic function of X, i.e. $\chi_X(x) = 1$ if $x\in X$, and $0$ otherwise.

I have problems parsing the RHS. Maybe I have spent too much of my time programming instead of doing math.

The superior limit of a sequence of *sets* is all elements that exists in infinitely many of those sets. What does it mean to take the superior limit of a sequence of *functions*? Is $\limsup_{n\to\infty}{\chi_{E_n}(x)}$ a set of values or a value?

For example, if $x \in E_{2n}$ but $x \notin E_{2n+1}$ for all $n$?

Comment: $\lim \sup A_n=\lim_{n \to \infty}\sup \{a_m: m \geq n\}$ for any sequence of real numbers $(a_n)$. $\lim \sup$ of a sequence of functions is taken in  point-wise sense.

Comment: Related:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1130477/liminf-of-a-sequence-of-functions